# Python program that finds most frequent word in a .txt file, Must print word and its count

Tags: python

As of right now, I have a function to replace the countChars function,

```
def countWords(lines):
  wordDict = {}
  for line in lines:
    wordList = lines.split()
    for word in wordList:
      if word in wordDict: wordDict[word] += 1
      else: wordDict[word] = 1
  return wordDict
```

but when I run the program it spits out this abomination (this is just an example, there's about two pages of words with a huge number count next to it)

```
before 1478
battle-field 1478
as 1478
any 1478
altogether 1478
all 1478
ago 1478
advanced. 1478
add 1478
above 1478
```

While obviously this means that the code is sound enough to run, I'm not getting what I want out of it.
It needs to print how many times each word is in the file (gb.txt, which is the Gettysburg address)
Obviously each word that is in the file isn't in there exactly 1478 times..

I'm pretty new at programming, so I'm kind of stumped..

```
from __future__ import division

inputFileName = 'gb.txt'

def readfile(fname):
  f = open(fname, 'r')
  s = f.read()
  f.close()
 return s.lower()

def countChars(t):
  charDict = {}
  for char in t:
    if char in charDict: charDict[char] += 1
    else: charDict[char] = 1
  return charDict

def findMostCommon(charDict):
  mostFreq = ''
  mostFreqCount = 0
  for k in charDict:
    if charDict[k] > mostFreqCount:
      mostFreqCount = charDict[k]
      mostFreq = k
  return mostFreq

def printCounts(charDict):
  for k in charDict:
    #First, handle some chars that don't show up very well when they print
    if k == '\n': print '\\n', charDict[k]  #newline
    elif k == ' ': print 'space', charDict[k]
    elif k == '\t': print '\\t', charDict[k] #tab
    else: print k, charDict[k]  #Normal character - print it with its count

def printAlphabetically(charDict):
  keyList = charDict.keys()
  keyList.sort()
  for k in keyList:
    #First, handle some chars that don't show up very well when they print
    if k == '\n': print '\\n', charDict[k]  #newline
    elif k == ' ': print 'space', charDict[k]
    elif k == '\t': print '\\t', charDict[k] #tab
    else: print k, charDict[k]  #Normal character - print it with its count

def printByFreq(charDict):
  aList = []
  for k in charDict:
    aList.append([charDict[k], k])
  aList.sort()     #Sort into ascending order
  aList.reverse()  #Put in descending order
  for item in aList:
    #First, handle some chars that don't show up very well when they print
    if item[1] == '\n': print '\\n', item[0]  #newline
    elif item[1] == ' ': print 'space', item[0]
    elif item[1] == '\t': print '\\t', item[0] #tab
    else: print item[1], item[0]  #Normal character - print it with its count

def main():
  text = readfile(inputFileName)
  charCounts = countChars(text)
  mostCommon = findMostCommon(charCounts)
  #print mostCommon + ':', charCounts[mostCommon]
  #printCounts(charCounts)
  #printAlphabetically(charCounts)
  printByFreq(charCounts)

main()
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to count a number of words in a passage, then it is better to use regex.

Let's start with a simple example:

```
import re

my_string = "Wow! Is this true? Really!?!? This is crazy!"

words = re.findall(r'\w+', my_string) #This finds words in the document
```

Result:

```
>>> words
['Wow', 'Is', 'this', 'true', 'Really', 'This', 'is', 'crazy']
```

Note that "Is" and "is" are two different words. My guess is that you want the to count them the same, so we can just capitalize all the words, and then count them.

```
from collections import Counter

cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words] #capitalizes all the words

word_counts = Counter(cap_words) #counts the number each time a word appears
```

Result:

```
>>> word_counts
Counter({'THIS': 2, 'IS': 2, 'CRAZY': 1, 'WOW': 1, 'TRUE': 1, 'REALLY': 1})
```

Are you good up to here?

Now we need to do exactly the same thing we did above just this time we are reading a file.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    passage = f.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)

cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words]

word_counts = Counter(cap_words)
```

Comment: Wow. While this may not be the method my professor wants us to use, this works perfectly for finding the number count.

At this point, I would preferably need to get them so they print in a single column for readability.
There are several parts to the assignment also, which include:
Just printing the most common word.
Printing all the words with their counts in alphabetical order.
And then print all the words with their counts in order of frequency.

These are pretty simple, if I'm not mistaken, but I don't know if what I have learned is compatible with what you've given me  so far.

Comment: The tasks you mention are not very difficult, you would need to use `.sort()` or `sorted()`, maybe search for how to sort a dictionary. It is your homework, and it is for you to do ;), but if you are stuck on some part, post what you have (as another question) and someone will help you out.

Comment: May I add that one can `passage = f.read().upper()` in one line

Answer (score 17):

This program is actually a 4-liner, if you use the powerful tools at your disposal:

```
with open(yourfile) as f:
    text = f.read()

words = re.compile(r"[\w']+", re.U).findall(text)   # re.U == re.UNICODE
counts = collections.Counter(words)
```

The regular expression will find all words, irregardless of the punctuation adjacent to them (but counting apostrophes as part of the word).

A counter acts almost just like a dictionary, but you can do things like `counts.most_common(10)`, and add counts, etc. See `help(Counter)`

I would also suggest that you not make functions `printBy...`, since only functions without side-effects are easy to reuse.

```
def countsSortedAlphabetically(counter, **kw):
    return sorted(counter.items(), **kw)

#def countsSortedNumerically(counter, **kw):
#    return sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], **kw)
#### use counter.most_common(n) instead

# `from pprint import pprint as pp` is also useful
def printByLine(tuples):
    print( '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,t)) for t in tuples) )
```

Demo:

```
>>> words = Counter(['test','is','a','test'])
>>> printByLine( countsSortedAlphabetically(words, reverse=True) )
test 2
is 1
a 1
```

*edit to address Mateusz Konieczny's comment: replaced [a-zA-Z'] with [\w']... the character class \w, according to the python docs, "Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched." (... but apparently doesn't match an apostrophe...) However \w includes _ and 0-9, so if you don't want those and you aren't working with unicode, you can use [a-zA-Z']; if you are working with unicode you'd need to do a negative assertion or something to subtract [0-9_] from the \w character class*

Comment: Yikes, I thought I had mentioned this was in Python 2.7.

Comment: @ZachCorse So is [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @ninjagecko Clearly you know what you're doing, but this seems to be ahead of what I've currently learned.
I'll probably sound silly, but when I try any of these things, more specifically the very first one you posted, I get a name error like this.

`words = re.compile(r"a-zA-Z'").findall(text)
NameError: name 're' is not defined`

Comment: Try starting with `import re`. `import collections` might help too.

Comment: `words = re.compile(r"a-zA-Z'").findall(text)` is broken for nonascii text (for example for Polish words - `text="Zażółć gęślą jaźń"`)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You have a simple typo, `words` where you want `word`.</strike>

Edit: You appear to have edited the source. Please use copy and paste to get it right the first time.

**Edit 2:** Apparently you're not the only one prone to typos. The real problem is that you have `lines` where you want `line`. I apologize for accusing you of editing the source.

Comment: Unsure of what you mean.
I replaced the function that searches for characters with the one that searches for words and replaced one word in the main function so that it would run.

Comment: When I remove the s from lines it only counts the characters.


EDIT: Oops, hit enter too quickly. I need it to count how many of each word there is within the file. With the lowercase s attached to lines it looks at how many words there are, but it does not count them. (there are numbers, but they are mostly all the same for some reason)

Answer (score 3):

```
 words = ['red', 'green', 'black', 'pink', 'black', 'white', 'black', 
'eyes','white', 'black', 'orange', 'pink', 'pink', 'red', 'red', 
'white', 'orange', 'white', "black", 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'pink', 
'green', 'pink','white', 'orange', "orange", 'red']

 from collections import Counter
 counts = Counter(words)
 top_four = counts.most_common(4)
 print(top_four)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a possible solution, not as elegant as ninjagecko's but still:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicto = defaultdict(int)

with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        s_line = line.rstrip().split(',') #assuming ',' is the delimiter
        for ele in s_line:
            dicto[ele] += 1

 #dicto contians words as keys, word counts as values

 for k,v in dicto.iteritems():
     print k,v
```

Comment: Maybe you should post a sample of your file, so we can see what the format looks like.

Comment: @ZachCorse: You might find http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-debug/index.html to be insightful when learning programming.

Answer (score 0):

Importing Collections and defining the function

```
from collections import Counter 
def most_count(n):
  split_it = data_set.split() 
  b=Counter(split_it)  
  return b.most_common(n)
```

Calling the functions specifying the top 'n' words you want. In my case n=15

```
most_count(15)
```