# Python Find the most frequent code

Tags: python, words

I want to read a file and find the most top frequent words. Here following is the code. I assume reading file I am making some mistake. Any suggestion will be appreciate.

```
txt_file = open('result.txt', 'r')

for line in txt_file:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        word = word.strip(punctuation).lower()

    all_words = nltk.FreqDist(word for word in word.words())
    top_words = set(all_words.keys()[:300])
    print top_words
```

Input result.txt file

```
Musik to shiyuki miyama opa samba japan obi Musik Musik Musik 
Antiques    antique 1900 s sewing pattern pictorial review size Musik 36 bust 1910 s ladies waist bust
```

Comment: Your fundamental problem seems to be that you're only looking at the last word of each line. You iterate over a line but don't store any of the words you find. `word.word()` is going to give you an error because `word` is a string and has no method `word()`.

Comment: This is the fundamental duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390989/python-program-that-finds-most-frequent-word-in-a-txt-file-must-print-word-and).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your error is, nor how to do it with NLTK, but your approach of looping through lines, then words can be adapted to use a simple python dictionary to keep track of counts:

```
txt_file = open("filename", "r")
txt_file.readLines()

wordFreq = {}
for line in txt_file:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        word = word.strip(punctuation).lower()
        # If word is already in dict, increase count
        if word in wordFreq:
            wordFreq[word] += 1
        else:    #Otherwise, add word to dict and initialize count to 1
            wordFreq[word] = 1
```

To query the results, just give the word of interest to the dict as a key, i.e. `wordFreq['Musik']`.

Comment: Better would be to use `defaultdict(int)` or Counter() from `collections`. Besides that, I'm not sure that you can read lines from txt_file in that way.

Comment: Well, I assume that was not his whole code and txt_file was generated as `fo = open("file", "r")`, `txt_file = fo.readLines()`

Comment: I think it's obvious from the first line of the code that `txt_file` is a file object. And OP question states that "he is making some mistake while reading the file" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
txt_file = open('result.txt', 'r')
words = [word for line in txt_file for word in line.strip().split()]
print Counter(words).most_common(1)
```

Instead of `1` in `most_common`, you can give any number and that much number of most frequently used data will be shown. For example

```
print Counter(words).most_common(1)
```

results in

```
[('Musik', 5)]
```

where as

```
print Counter(words).most_common(5)
```

gives

```
[('Musik', 5), ('bust', 2), ('s', 2), ('antique', 1), ('ladies', 1)]
```

the number is actually an optional parameter, if you omit that, it will give frequencies of all the words in the descending order.