# Frequencies in a text file and creating a pie chart

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, charts, pie-chart, frequency

I have a very large text files. I want to analyze it and plot those analyses. One analysis I have done is finding the 5 most common words.

```
     f = open('story.txt','r')
        words = [x for y in [l.split() for l in f.readlines()] for x in y]
        data = sorted([(w, words.count(w)) for w in set(words)], key = lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:5] 

    print data

    most_words = [x[0] for x in data]
    times_used = [int(x[1]) for x in data]
    print most_words
    print times_used
```

Displays this:

```
[('the', 4826), ('of', 2276), ('and', 1825), ('a', 1761), ('to', 1693)]
['the', 'of', 'and', 'a', 'to']
[4826, 2276, 1825, 1761, 1693]
```

Since this is such a large file, it takes a while to analyze. First I wanted to know if there was a way to do this in a much faster way? Second I wanted to create a pie chart with this data. Ive managed to figure out how to make a bar graph with this data, but making a pie chart seems to elude me. Any help would be great!

Again, if there is a way to speed up searching through a large text file and not using so much RAM in the proccess, I can hear my computer running hard whe I run this. Thank you!

.. Or if there is any posts you believe may help please let me know, I have been searching for solutions to my questions for over an hour and decided to ask my own question for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the plot part you can do it using the following recipe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

words = [('the', 4826), ('of', 2276), ('and', 1825), ('a', 1761), ('to', 1693)]
sizes, labels = [i[1] for i in words],[i[0] for i in words]
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels,autopct='%1.1i%%')
plt.show()
```

, which results in this:

[image: Pie chart in matplotlib for word frequency]

You can give other arguments for color, explosions, and so on. Check [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html) matplotlib demo.

For the performance part I advise you to take a look into this post:

[Python program that finds most frequent word in a .txt file, Must print word and its count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390989/python-program-that-finds-most-frequent-word-in-a-txt-file-must-print-word-and)

@ninjagecko solution seems to me the one that might be faster, but you'll have to test it and see.

Comment: You are awesome! The other frequency counter works much better and the pie chart is great! i see where I was making my mistake, Thank you very much!