# Search for repeating word in text

Tags: jython

I haven't found any straight answers.

I need to find the words in text / string that is being repeated the most.
E.g.
String that has following values:

```
000587\local_users
000587\local_users
4444\et-4444
et\pmostowiak
et\pmostowiak
et\pmostowiak
```

Then the results needs to be et\pmostowiak

How should I accomplish this?

EDIT:
I'm using older version of jython so I can't use the collections library with Counter function

This prints all values that are found more than ones:

```
d = {}

for x in users: 
  d[x] = x in d

_result = [x for x in d if d[x]] # [1]
```

If I could reuse this further?

Comment: what differentiates a word? line based?

Comment: In this case yes a line break

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list ...

Comment: if `s` is string, `import collections` and `print(collections.Counter(s.split('\n')).most_common(1)[0][0])`

Comment: It's nearly a duplicate - unless the problem was splitting a string, which will be a duplicate too - but it's two questions really

Comment: I think this is a better duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390989/python-program-that-finds-most-frequent-word-in-a-txt-file-must-print-word-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have some iterable container of words, `collections` does exactly what you need.

```
>>> import collections
>>> words = ['000587\local_users', '000587\local_users', '4444\et-4444', 'et\pmostowiak', 'et\pmostowiak', 'et\pmostowiak']
>>> print collections.Counter(words).most_common(1)
[('et\\pmostowiak', 3)]
```

This begs the question of how to `split` a string. 
This works:

```
>>> str = """000587\local_users
... 000587\local_users
... 4444\et-4444
... et\pmostowiak
... et\pmostowiak
... et\pmostowiak"""
>>> str.split('\n')
['000587\\local_users', '000587\\local_users', '4444\\et-4444', 'et\\pmostowiak', 'et\\pmostowiak', 'et\\pmostowiak']
>>> words = str.split('\n')
```

Comment: Sorry guys my bad:

Comment: I kind forget to mention that I'm dealing with an older version of jython and thereby the collections library is not supported.. sorry about this

Comment: @user2023042 In that case you should probably update the actual question and tags to reflect this.

Comment: @user2023042 once you have the words, you could figure out how to count the frequencies; a dictionary of words to their counts would work

Comment: counting freq with dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2161792/4082052

Comment: Thanks I check that dictionary out