# Total number of first words in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a program that counts the top 5 most common first words of the lines in a file and which does not include lines where the first word is followed by a "DM" or an "RT"?

I don't have any code as of so far because I'm completely lost.

```
f = open("C:/Users/Joe Simpleton/Desktop/talking.txt", "r")
?????
```

Comment: Iterate over the file and implement your constraints using if statements. There are plenty of tutorials on the web that show you how to read files by line.

Comment: One suggestion (not meant glibly) is to google `"python counter"`.

Comment: [This may be of use to you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10390989/9348376).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not tested, but should work roughly like that:

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter()
with open("path") as f:
     for line in f:
          parts = line.split(" ")
          if parts[1] not in ["DM", "RT"]:
                count[parts[0]] += 1
     print(count.most_common(5))
```

You should also add a check that ensures that parts has > 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Read each line of your text in. For each line, split it into words using a regular expression, this will return a list of the words. If there are at least two words, test the second word to make sure it is not in your list. Then use a [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) to keep track of all of the word counts. Store the lowercase of each word so that uppercase and lowercase versions of the same word are not counted separately:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

word_counts = Counter()

with open('talking.txt') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', line)

        if (len(words) > 1 and words[1] not in ['DM', 'RT']) or len(words) == 1:
            word_counts.update(word.lower() for word in words)

print(word_counts.most_common(5))
```

The `Counter()` has a useful feature in being able to show the most common values.